# communication between 2 components

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

I'm new to Angular and need help please.

I have two components..one for index and one for Navigation.

for the index component there are subcomponents, which is changed by a value of a variable productDivision..so if productDivision = 1, the sub-component (A) will be shown in the index and if the productDivision = 2, the subcomponent (B) will be shown instead of (A).

so what I need is ... if I click an element on the navbar, i want the value of the prodDivision to change..to display the different sub-component in the index 
so how can I take the new value of prodDivision  variable from HTML and assign it to typescript as a new value of the variable prodDivision?

navbar component: html:

```
<nav id="nav-icons">
    <a class="nav-icon-home" (click)="prodDivision === null; detectProductDivision() " routerLink="/">
      <span class="nav-icon"></span><br />
      Telefon
    </a>
    <a class="nav-icon-mobile" (click)="prodDivision === 1 ;detectProductDivision()" routerLink="/" >
      <span class="nav-icon"></span><br />
      Mobil
    </a>

    <a class="nav-icon-phone" (click)="prodDivision === 2; detectProductDivision()" routerLink="/">
      <span class="nav-icon"></span><br />
      Fax
    </a>
```

navbar.ts

```
  import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navbar',
      templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
    })
    export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

         public prodDivision: number;
        @Output() public navbarEmitter = new EventEmitter();
      constructor() { }
        detectProductDivision() {
            this.navbarEmitter.emit(this.prodDivision);
        }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: do you want the proDivision value in navbar.ts?

Comment: it's very unclear. are you sure that you read enough docs about angular routing before trying anything ?

Comment: Read about these `event emitters` ,`output decorator`, `input decorator` etc. Asking questions without reading documentation is higlhy discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service to hold communication between any number of components

I made a demo according to your need, check in [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dshmkz)